# output web page as text only from javascript

Tags: javascript, plaintext, document.write

I have an ASP.NET page using a master page.  On that I have a script, what I would like to do is to rewrite the output of the HTML to just give me a street name without all the HTML headers etc.

Here's the script, can you please advise on how to do this?

```
    function getAddress(Latitude, Longitude) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var Lat = parseFloat(Latitude);
        var Lng = parseFloat(Longitude);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // document.clear();
                document.open();
                document.write(results[0].formatted_address);
                document.close();
            }
            else {
                // Do nothing
                document.open();
                document.write('');
                document.close();
            }
            geocoder = null;
        });
    }
```

I don't have to use the master page (I might try it without after I post this question).

I know document.write is considered bad practice but above is only an example of what I'm trying to do.

I will be calling this page from my VB.NET application using HTTP request etc. so all I want back is a plain text file with the street name.

Answer (score 0):

When you will load your page with ASP.NET, javascript will not be executed.
Moreover, you can't change the type of your page with javascript.

You may find another solution, a nicer one please :-)

Comment: ok i don't really needs ASP (more out of habit then anything else that I created the page as ASP), so if I change it to HTML, could I do what I need?